# Angular, spy on Location.go in unit test karma/jasmine

Tags: angular

My component does a simple rewrite of the url using location.go:

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(private location: Location){}
...
this.location.go(`${this.router.url}/${this.projectId}`);
```

My unit test fails saying `Expected spy go to have been called`

```
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
...
configureTestSuite(() => {
  ...
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    ...
    imports: [..., RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [
      Location,
    ],
    ...
  });

  loc = TestBed.get(Location);
});
...
describe('Add Project', () => {
  it('should add new project', fakeAsync(() => {
  ...
  spyOn(loc, 'go');
  ...
  tick();
  expect(loc.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
  }));
});
```

Comment: have you tried `const a = spyOn(loc, 'go'); expect(a)... `? Another thought: using createSpyObj to mock the whole location obj

Comment: @enno.void both of those resulted in the same fail message as before :/

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more context. Where are you calling the location.go?